# Custom error when using ISO Dates in Spring as path variables?

Tags: java, spring, datetime-format

Scenario :

I am able to provide my endpoint with dates, and I am able to use the @DateTimeFormat annotation in order to make sure they are formatted correctly. However, Instead of JUST returning the 400 error if they are not, I'd like to instead build up my response with an error message to be included, too.

Current endpoint :

```
@GetMapping("/startDate/{startDate}/endDate/{endDate}")
public ResponseEntity<?> performSearchByDateAction(
        @PathVariable @DateTimeFormat(iso=DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) Date startDate,
        @PathVariable @DateTimeFormat(iso=DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) Date endDate) throws ParseException {

    System.out.println(lastChangedStart);
    System.out.println(lastChangedEnd);

    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

Please ignore the fact that all this endpoint does is output some dates, and then responds with an "Ok" status. My issue here is that if I hit the endpoint with an incorrectly formatted date, I just get the 400 bad request response because the annotation handles it - but in reality I want to build my 400 response in the response entity so that I can provide a message about the dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@GetMapping("/startDate/{startDate}/endDate/{endDate}")
public ResponseEntity<?> performSearchByDateAction(
        @PathVariable String startDateAsString,
        @PathVariable String endDateAsString) throws ParseException {
    DateTime lastChangedStart = null;
    try {
        lastCangedStart = DateTimeFormatter.parse(startDateAsString);
    } catch (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException e) {
         try { // second format
         } catch (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException e) {
              try { // third format
              } catch (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException e) {
         }
     } catch (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException e) {
    System.out.println(lastChangedStart);
    System.out.println(lastChangedEnd);

    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

There's probably an easier way to do it, but this works for me.